# Creating a random quiz with buttons app for android, but crashes if the first questions displays first

Tags: android, button, random, numbers

I'm trying to create a random quiz app, but i'm facing a particular problem that i was not able to solve in the last 2 days.

I have all my questions and options inside of 2 different array of Strings. An int called flag which determines the progress of the quiz

```
int flag=0; 

String allQuestions[]={"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"};

String allOptions[]={/*/Primeras opciones /*/"A","I","O",
                     /*/Segundas opciones/*/"E","O","I",
                     /*/Terceras opciones/*/"A","I","U",
                      /*/Cuartas opciones/*/"O","E","U",
                       */Quintas opciones/*/"O","U","A",
                            /*/Sextas opciones/*/"I","U","E",
                            /*/Septimas opciones/*/"E","I","E"
                            /*/Octavas opciones/*/"A","I","U",
                            /*/Novenas opciones/*/"E","U","O",
                            /*/Decimas opciones/*/"A","O","U"};
```

This is how i pick the random numbers:

```
ArrayList<Integer> number = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) number.add(i);
    Collections.shuffle(number);
```

I have my buttons linked and make their text change once the quiz activity is created.

```
question=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.QuizCharacter);
    answerA=(Button)findViewById(R.id.answerA);
    answerB=(Button)findViewById(R.id.answerB);
    answerC=(Button)findViewById(R.id.answerC);
    answerD=(Button)findViewById(R.id.answerD);
    answerE=(Button)findViewById(R.id.answerE);
    answerF=(Button)findViewById(R.id.answerF);

    question.setText(number.get(flag));     // <------ having problems here?
    answerA.setText(allOptions[0]);
    answerB.setText(allOptions[1]);
    answerC.setText(allOptions[2]);
    answerD.setText(allOptions[3]);
    answerE.setText(allOptions[4]);
    answerF.setText(allOptions[5]);
```

Now, the randomizer works, the problem is that if the created random number is the first question A, then the app crashes.
I tried changing what i assume is the problematic line for

question.setText(allQuestions[number.get(0)]);

And instead of having a chance to randomize, it crashes every time.

Why is it happening and how can i fix it?

EDIT:

onCreate method:

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz1);

    correct = 0;
    flag=0;


    ArrayList<Integer> number = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) number.add(i);
    Collections.shuffle(number);


    String questionCounter = "Question number (flag+1): " + (flag + 1);//+ "\nnumber.get(flag)="+ number.get(flag);

    TextView questionNumber;
    questionNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionNumber);
    questionNumber.setText(questionCounter);


    question.setText(allQuestions[number.get(0)]);
    answerA=(Button)findViewById(R.id.answerA);
    answerB=(Button)findViewById(R.id.answerB);
    answerC=(Button)findViewById(R.id.answerC);
    answerD=(Button)findViewById(R.id.answerD);
    answerE=(Button)findViewById(R.id.answerE);
    answerF=(Button)findViewById(R.id.answerF);

    question.setText(allQuestions[number.get(flag)]);
    answerA.setText(allOptions[0]);
    answerB.setText(allOptions[1]);
    answerC.setText(allOptions[2]);
    answerD.setText(allOptions[3]);
    answerE.setText(allOptions[4]);
    answerF.setText(allOptions[5]);
}
```

Edit 2:

Thanks to Shadab Ansari for the answer. I forgot to initialize the variable question.

Comment: Please post the logcat output containing the crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not storing anything at `0th index` of `number`.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) number.add(i); //Runs from 1 to 10
```

Your loop should change to -

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) number.add(i); //Runs from 0 to 9
```

Also, according to the logs, `"question"` may be null. So please initialize all the views before using it.

Comment: I misunderstood the question, this answer is correct.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply, sadly that didn't solve my problem, `for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) number.add(i); `
nor `or (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) number.add(i); `
      

stops the crash from happening. Any other idea?

Comment: In my answer it is (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) not (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) .Paste the logcat output after trying my code.

Comment: I pasted what i found highligthed with red in the logcat output after the app crashing, i hope that helps you find the solution i'm looking for.

Comment: Paste your activity's onCreate() method.

Comment: There. it might be inconsistent because i was trying different outputs, but don't worry about it, i will change it once i find the answer.

Comment: Where is "allQuestions" declared ?

Comment: After declaring the class name together with other variables:
public class Quiz1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView question;
    RadioGroup rg;
    Button answerA;
    Button answerB;
    Button answerC;
    Button answerD;
    Button answerE;
    Button answerF;
    //Syllables order: A I U E O
    String allQuestions[]={"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"};

Comment: you are not following properly. I asked you to use my exact code first. Then run it and then if you face the crash, post the updated code and fresh logs.

Comment: You are still using  i < 9 in the loop and not  i < 10

Comment: Sorry i was just trying it again, (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) still provoques the crash. I just changed it back.

Comment: Where is "question" initialized which you are using in " question.setText(allQuestions[number.get(0)]);"  ?

Comment: Right after the class name:
 TextView question;
Let me place that in the post too since it looks very confusing in the comment.

Comment: I am talking about initialization not declaration.

Comment: Oh, i don't think i did, i'm trying it right now.
Edit: 
That was it, i can't belive i missed that, thank you so much, i've been stuck with this crash for 2 days now, i wish i have asked for help sooner.